# Xcode doesn't generate memgraph file after UI Test finishes execution?

Tags: xcode, xctest, uitest, wwdc

I'm following this video Detect and diagnose memory from WWDC 2021: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10180/

In the video, after the UI test finishes execution, a memgraph is generated. I created a new project and added some UI tests, but after all the tests finished execution, Xcode didn't generate any memgraph.

Here is my test that follows the example in WWDC video:

```
func testExample() throws {
        // UI tests must launch the application that they test.
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        let options = XCTMeasureOptions()
        options.invocationOptions = [.manuallyStart]

        measure(
            metrics: [XCTMemoryMetric(application: app)],
            options: options
        ) {
            app.launch()

            startMeasuring()

            app.staticTexts["Abandoned Memory Example"].tap()
            app.buttons["Scenarios"].tap()

            app.staticTexts["Leaks Memory Example"].tap()

            let simulateLogoutThenLoginActionButton = app.buttons["Simulate Logout then Login Action"]
            simulateLogoutThenLoginActionButton.tap()
            simulateLogoutThenLoginActionButton.tap()
            simulateLogoutThenLoginActionButton.tap()
            simulateLogoutThenLoginActionButton.tap()

            XCTAssertTrue(true)
        }
    }
```

What I've tried:

- In UI Test scheme, I unchecked the "Attachments: Delete when each test succeeds"
- I checked "Malloc Stack Logging"

I'm using Xcode 14.2.

How can I make Xcode generate a memgraph after UI test finishes execution?
Thanks in advance for your help!